# In drf-yasg,How does a POST request carry URL-encoded parameters?

Tags: drf-yasg

```
@swagger_auto_schema(method='post', operation_id="login", manual_parameters=[
    openapi.Parameter('phone', "query",openapi.IN_FORM,
                      type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, required=True,),
    openapi.Parameter('vercode', "query",openapi.IN_FORM,type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, required=True,), ],
    content_type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    responses={200: "successful", 400: 'not support', 401: 'invalid phone', 403:'query failed'}, tags=tags,)
@api_view(['POST'])
@action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
def login(request):
    pass
```

As above, I executed in the browser and found that the parameters were carried in the URL:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?phone=12345678&vercode=12345

This statement doesn't seem to work：

```
    content_type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
```

because I want to carry data in the body：

such as:

POST data : "phone=12345678&vercode=852073"

How to modify swagger_auto_schema?

I don't know what to do. Please help me.